# Application Health Dashboard - what's hot

Tags: .net, health-monitoring

Looking into some sort of dashboard/report tool for monitoring the general health of one or more application. I'm thinking IIS events, application log (Enterprise/log4net/...) and so forth. Can anyone recommande a couple to look into?